# watch the value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to watch the array value of ng-model in angularjs i have created fiddle but does not work Please take a look and suggest.

Thanks

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in profiles track by $index">
                 <td>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="parktime_{{user.user_id}}"
                      ng-model="orderItems[user.user_id].parktime"
                      >
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>



 function ParentCtrl($scope) {
    }

    function ChildCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.parkOptions = {};
        $scope.profiles = [
            {user_id: '01', park_name: 'England Park'},
            {user_id: '02', park_name: 'France Park'}
        ];
 $scope.orderItems = {};
$scope.orderItems.parktime = "Test";

        $scope.$watch('orderItems[profiles.user_id].parktime', function(newVal, oldVal){
            console.log(newVal);
        })

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5vskLfc/59/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead. You can't use watch this way, it is to watch a single property instead.

I've also updated your model to use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). This is something you should be careful with using, but in your case, you need to have an key defined at each position of your `orderItems` object. If you will always statically assign these, I recommend iterating through them once and creating a key that way instead.

**HTML**

```
      <input type="text" name="parktime_{{user.user_id}}"
      ng-init="orderItems[user.user_id] = {}"
      ng-model="orderItems[user.user_id].parktime"
      ng-change="onChange(user.user_id)">
```

**JS**

```
   $scope.onChange = function(items) {
        console.log(items);
   }
```

Comment: I have datetime-picker in the text box it does not shows me console if i am using it into my fiddle it says safe is undefined

Comment: Could you update your example with what you are actually doing? We can only answer based on what we're given. If you are using a jQuery library to change the value, that would be why Angular has no idea what's going on.

Comment: In that example, you didn't add ng-init, so the model is undefined. You also didn't declare  `$scope.orderItems` in your controller.

Comment: Yes, this is correct but I want to see if new value found in the model that get updated, because i m not typing anything i'm selecting date and time only

Sorry for that. but i apprecaited your time pls guide if you can

Comment: angular.forEach(userInfo, function(user, key){
      $scope.$watch('[orderItems[user.user_id].flight_arrival_time, orderItems[user.user_id].departure_flight_time]', function(newVal, oldVal){
      if (newVal !== oldVal && typeof oldVal !== 'undefined') {        
        var orderItems = {
            'order_id' : $scope.order.order_id,
            'flg_time' : newVal[0],
            'dep_time' : newVal[1],
        }
        $scope.saveOrder(user, orderItems);
      }
    }, true);
  });

Comment: var userInfo = auth.getCurrentUser().children; i WAS TRYING SOMETHINGLIKE THAT

Comment: You'll have to update this question with more details. What are you using for your datepicker? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker? If not, I would suggest you try that if you are using some sort of jQuery library.

Comment: I am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-datetime-picker

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access indexes which does not exist. *profiles* is an array of objects and I don't think there is anything available on *profiles.user_id* index. Also, I don't think *orderItems[profiles.user_id]* will work as that index also doesn't exist.